# Device tree - How to add 2 spi chip on 1 spi bus?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, spi, device-tree

I am trying to add 2 TI's CC2520 chip on Raspberry Pi 3's SPI, which has 2 spi chip select pin. However, I can only add one chip, on either chip select 0 or 1, but not both.

Adding the following at the end of bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dts, I can see "wpan0" ethernet interface by "ifconfig"

```
&spi0 {
status="okay";
spidev@0{
    status = "disabled";
};
spidev@1{
    status = "disabled";
};
cc2520@0 {
    compatible = "ti,cc2520";
    reg = <0>;
    spi-max-frequency = <4000000>;
    fifo-gpio = <&gpio 24 1>;
    fifop-gpio = <&gpio 17 1>;
    sfd-gpio = <&gpio 4 1>;
    cca-gpio = <&gpio 23 1>;
    vreg-gpio = <&gpio 26 1>;  /*LED*/
    reset-gpio = <&gpio 25 1>;  /*connected to two 2520*/
};
```

This one also work

```
&spi0 {
status="okay";
spidev@0{
    status = "disabled";
};
spidev@1{
    status = "disabled";
};
cc2520@1 {
    compatible = "ti,cc2520";
    reg = <1>;
    spi-max-frequency = <4000000>;
    fifo-gpio = <&gpio 12 1>;
    fifop-gpio = <&gpio 6 1>;
    sfd-gpio = <&gpio 5 1>;
    cca-gpio = <&gpio 16 1>;
    vreg-gpio = <&gpio 19 1>;  /*IO5 actually, it is input*/
    reset-gpio = <&gpio 18 1>;  /*just a NC pin*/
};
```

But adding the following node, my Linux can not boot. The RPI3 get stuck at the initial color screen

```
&spi0 {
status="okay";
spidev@0{
    status = "disabled";
};
spidev@1{
    status = "disabled";
};
cc2520@0 {
    compatible = "ti,cc2520";
    reg = <0>;
    spi-max-frequency = <4000000>;
    fifo-gpio = <&gpio 24 1>;
    fifop-gpio = <&gpio 17 1>;
    sfd-gpio = <&gpio 4 1>;
    cca-gpio = <&gpio 23 1>;
    vreg-gpio = <&gpio 26 1>;  /*LED*/
    reset-gpio = <&gpio 25 1>;  /*connected to two 2520*/
};
cc2520@1 {
    compatible = "ti,cc2520";
    reg = <1>;
    spi-max-frequency = <4000000>;
    fifo-gpio = <&gpio 12 1>;
    fifop-gpio = <&gpio 6 1>;
    sfd-gpio = <&gpio 5 1>;
    cca-gpio = <&gpio 16 1>;
    vreg-gpio = <&gpio 19 1>;  /*IO5 actually, it is input*/
    reset-gpio = <&gpio 18 1>;  /*just a NC pin*/
};
```

I have already tried to replace one CC2520 node to some ATMEL chip, although I don't have it. But the device tree simply do not allow 2 chip appear on 1 spi bus. Any idea?

Thanks,
Alan